# Context Variables should be created at the top module level and never in closures

Tags: python-3.x, closures, python-contextvars

In the documentation for the Python standard library module contextvars, it is stated that:

> Context Variables should be created at the top module level and never within closures.

However, I am unclear about the meaning of this statement. While many online tutorials mention it, none provide an explanation. Could you please provide an example where a context variable is created within a closure, and explain the potential problems it may cause? Is it related to GC?

> Context objects hold strong references to context variables which prevents context variables from being properly garbage collected.